# Negative Margin in Firefox Using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap plugin, mainly just the grid system currently.

I am trying to put one row on top of another doing some stuff for responsive design.

In Chrome this works perfectly:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content">
            abcd
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="moveUpRow">
        <div class="content">
            efgh
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    height: 200px;
}

#moveUpRow {
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

But in Firefox and IE they both ignore the negative margin. I have tried `top: -200px`, but that just moves up the `row` and not all of the elements below the row. Leaving big white space.

Any other solutions to this problem? Or any suggestions on how to "pull" up any content below the row?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Because I have two background colors that span two different rows and I am trying to get part of them to overlap. So I wanted to see if it is possible. If it is, great. If not, I'll try something else.

Comment: Still don't really get what you are trying to do, but if you make #moveUpRow { position:absolute; } the content below it will not be pushed down.

Comment: Try insert `!important` in style like `margin-top: -200px !important;`

Comment: @PiLHA tried that already. No luck.

Comment: Your code works fine on this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8evrf/ which means it's likely to be a css conflict on your site. If you have a link then that would be helpful..

Comment: @Omega Thanks, I think it is a problem with the way bootstrap uses floats for the rows and columns possibly throwing things off. I'll just need to go through and clear some of those. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @BarryTormey No problem, if you do have a link then add it in a comment and I'll take a look, it might be better then clearing parts of your css. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. In my case I had two floating elements in my first row, so when I placed a negative margin to the second one it would move the entire row. Weirdly it worked fine in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Try adding overflow:hidden; to the row if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you posted and CSS looks good to me in Firefox and IE, see http://www.bootply.com/72944

Perhaps you could start by double checking the paths to your CSS files and make sure there isn't some other problem with the HTML on your page?

Good luck!